# Weird character output in countdown algorithm with more than 4 char input

Tags: c, arrays, string

I'm trying to take an input string like `12340` and output `4321`. The weird thing is, if I put a sequence that is smaller than 4 (ex : `1230`), the output is correct (`321`). But if I input `12340`, I end up having `4321(↨@`. What causes this behavior?

(This is no homework, I'm following exercice 6.8 of http://www.ltam.lu/cours-c/prg-c58.htm to learn C)

Here is my whole code (I would post a small/concise code example but I can't seem to put the finger on the problem)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char array[100];

    printf("Shoot me consecutive numbers, end with 0\n");
    scanf("%s",&array);
    int count = strlen(array);
    char countdown[count];
    int reverseIndex;
    int index = 0;
    for(reverseIndex = count-1;reverseIndex >= 0;reverseIndex--)
    {
        char possibleNumber = array[reverseIndex];
        if(isdigit(possibleNumber) && possibleNumber != '0')
        {
            countdown[index] = possibleNumber;
            index++;
        }
    }
    printf("countdown : %s\n",countdown);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Initialize the contents of `countdown`.  I used `memset()` to init all elements to `0`, that (and addressing a couple of other issues) enabled it to run as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***One immediate error*** is this line:

you need to provide enough room for the NULL terminator in this line:

```
char countdown[count + 1];//added +1
```

***Another is***:

```
scanf("%s",&array);
```

Change it to:

```
scanf("%s",array); //%s expects char *, &array is of type char (*)[100], parameter type mismatch
```

***I made these edits*** to the original code (see in-line comments), also used call to `memset()` to initialize countdown, and it runs: (results shown below)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char array[100];

    printf("Shoot me consecutive numbers, end with 0\n");
    scanf("%s",array);//removed &
    int count = strlen(array);
    char countdown[count+1];//add room for NULL terminator
    int reverseIndex;
    int index = 0;
    memset(countdown, 0, count+1);//added to initialize all elements of char array to NULL
    for(reverseIndex = count-1;reverseIndex >= 0;reverseIndex--)
    {
        char possibleNumber = array[reverseIndex];
        if(isdigit(possibleNumber) && possibleNumber != '0')
        {
            countdown[index] = possibleNumber;
            index++;
        }
    }
    printf("countdown : %s\n",countdown);

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

***Input and output***:

[image]

***EDIT*** to answer comment question about undesired characters in result
(and original question: *...But if I input 12340, I end up having 4321(↨@...* )

When `char countdown[count+1];` is created, there is no guarantee of the contents.
That is, each position can be filled with any random set of bits.
Say array is defined as char array[5];  If not initialized, it may look like this in memory:

```
|€|Œ|™|¢|§|
```

Later in your code, you loop through to make assignments to each position to
populate with characters obtained using `scanf() from stdin, which is fine,
Now, it looks like this after looping 4 times:

```
|1|2|3|4|§|
```

Note, there is not a terminating NULL (0) in the last position.
By using `memset(array, 0, 5);` the created buffer would look like this:

```
|0|0|0|0|0|
```

And the resulting populated buffer like this:

```
|1|2|3|4|0|  //properly terminated char buf is required for a C string
```

Comment: Either will work. The array will degenerate to a pointer in your recommendation. This is not the problem.

Comment: @Quirliom `scanf("%s",&array);` is a mistake although it is likely to work on modern systems. The `%s` expects a `char *` argument, however `&array` is of type `char (*)[100]`. These could , in theory, have different sizes and representations.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - I just tested it, using C99,  I get a parameter type mismatch, (non fatal) supporting your suspicion,  leading to a failure to populate the buffers.

Comment: @ryyker it seems unlikely to me that you would actually get a failure to populate the array. You didn't perhaps write `char *array` instead of `char array[100]` ?

Comment: @MattMcNabb - No.  Used `char array[100];` and `scanf("%s",&array);` exactly. (my code is above, except the `&array`)  `scanf()` threw the parm mismatch error, then program execution flow continued onto the next line without allowing input to stdin.  Buffers were not populated, and loop was therefore bypassed.  Curious, on what type of system would you expect this to be tolerated?

Comment: I agree it isn't correct, but it works on [ideone](http://ideone.com/oPUzaC) and worked in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @ryyker I'd expect it to work on all modern systems. [See it working](http://ideone.com/CpEAX8)

Comment: @RetiredNinja - weird, but okay.  Thanks.

Comment: It may be a C99 specific thing.

Comment: @MattMcNabb - Thanks.  My system is current, up to date (2013 implementation of C99), so not sure what to make of both yours, and RetiredNinja's findings.  do-do-do-do, do-do-do-do  (to the tune of Twilight Zone)

Comment: @ryyker you're probably making some other mistake that you are misattributing to being due to this issue

Comment: @MattMcNabb - That could very well be.  Its late here, and my ability to making any good observations is quickly diminishing.  :)  Although I did just try checking the output of `scanf()`, it is zero, and the array buffer is empty.  I'll look at it again tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though do you know why I didn't get the output with `1230` but I did get it with `12340`. This is bugging me!

Comment: @TopinFrassi - 2 things I think:  Space and initialization.  Your original line: char countdown[count]; was not created with enough space to contain the intended characters AND a terminating NULL. In my example, I changed it to: char countdown[count+1];. Note, that even though space is provided for the NULL, it is also important to Place it. That can ba addressed by initialization.  See my edit for a better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

The countdown array isn't NULL terminated so printf doesn't know where to stop.

You'll want to allocate count + 1 characters and then set the last character to NULL.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char array[100];

    printf("Shoot me consecutive numbers, end with 0\n");
    scanf("%s",&array);
    int count = strlen(array);
    char countdown[count + 1];
    int reverseIndex;
    int index = 0;
    for(reverseIndex = count-1;reverseIndex >= 0;reverseIndex--)
    {
        char possibleNumber = array[reverseIndex];
        if(isdigit(possibleNumber) && possibleNumber != '0')
        {
            countdown[index] = possibleNumber;
            index++;
        }
    }
    countdown[index] = 0;
    printf("countdown : %s\n",countdown);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curious if the line:  `scanf("%s",&array);` does not cause you problems.  I get  a parameter type mismatch, leading to a failure to populate the buffers.